# Salesforce Managed Package Installation Error Sandbox

Tags: managed-package, package, app-install

I am installing Package in Sandbox , It will not Installing

I am installing same in Developer Edition Installing fine.

What is reason not installing in Sandbox

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Not Error It shows like this Your request is in progress. You will be notified by email when it completes.

Comment: Is the sandbox on Spring14?  I have seen package installs take days in the past around upgrade window time.

Comment: yes Spring14 Sandbox.I installed this apps 4 days before now also it showing "Your request is in progress. You will be notified by email when it completes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Apps limits exceed in sandbox. that is reason it showing "Your request is in progress. You will be notified by email when it completes."